# Get matplotlib color from style palette

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

I need to add some background lines to my figures, such as bold lines for `x=0` and `y=0` and a diagonal. Every time I change color scheme / "style" of the figure I have to change manually the color of these lines.

Is there a way to retrieve the colors of a current figure's style?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure I fully understand what you are trying to achieve, but you might find `plt.style.library` useful:

Let's take `bmh` style as an example.

Calling `plt.style.library['bmh']` will produce:

```
RcParams({u'axes.edgecolor': u'#bcbcbc',
          u'axes.facecolor': u'#eeeeee',
          u'axes.grid': True,
          u'axes.labelsize': u'large',
          u'axes.prop_cycle': cycler(u'color', [u'#348ABD', u'#A60628', u'#7A68A6', u'#467821', u'#D55E00', u'#CC79A7', u'#56B4E9', u'#009E73', u'#F0E442', u'#0072B2']),
          u'axes.titlesize': u'x-large',
          u'legend.fancybox': True,
          u'lines.linewidth': 2.0,
          u'mathtext.fontset': u'cm',
          u'patch.antialiased': True,
          u'patch.edgecolor': u'#eeeeee',
          u'patch.facecolor': u'blue',
          u'patch.linewidth': 0.5,
          u'text.hinting_factor': 8})
```

So if you need a particular setting you access it like this:

```
plt.style.library['bmh']['axes.facecolor']
```

which gives:

```
u'#eeeeee'
```

P.S. Above code assumes you have this import:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Comment: thank you! and how do you get which colour scheme is currently activated?

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way to do that with `matplotlib`'s built-in functions. As far as I can tell it comes down to checking what values are active in your `rcParams`.